# Ajax Call executing twice?

Tags: php, jquery

Why is this ajax call giving me back both answers? First, and in a barely noticeable way the correct answer, then the other one?

**The Form page**

```
   $(document).on('click','.save-action',function(){
                    //var text = tinyMCE.get('#action-desc').getContent(); 
                    if($("#form-save-action").validationEngine('validate'))
                    {

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            cache: false,
                            data: $("#form-save-action").serialize(),
                            url:"modules/actions/insertaction.php",      

                            success : function (data) {

                               $("#response-message").html(data);

                            }
                        })
                    }

                });
```

Adicionar Acção
    
      Nome da acção 
      
        

      


      Descrição

---

Gravar

**Insertaction.php**

```
$exists = $action->actionExists($actionName);



if($exists == 0)
{
        $action->insertAction(array($actionName,$action->clearContent($actionDesc),1));
        echo 'Acção adicionada com sucesso!'; 
}
if($exists >= 1)
{
      echo 'Acção já existe!'; 
}
```

So if I click in the .save-action button, it gives me back first the correct answer, then the other one.

PS: the ajax call is wrapped in a `$(document).ready`function

Comment: Is this form being loaded in dynamically?

Comment: is `.save-action` in an <a> tag? try doing e.preventDefault();

Comment: Yes to both. And @karthikr, e.preventDefault() does nothing :(

Comment: put a `return false;` at the end

Comment: Are the script only included once in the page? It seems like the script might be included twice..?

Comment: How are you loading the form in dynamically? Every time it gets loaded in and that javascript executes, another click event will be bound to the document.

Comment: probably you binding the same function on the element twice

Comment: Please post the HTML... What we're hinting at is that you are calling the function twice.  It'll help if we had the full source...

Comment: Move your script off of the form page and to the global page so that the script doesn't get ran more than once. Since you are using event delegation, it doesn't need to run every time you load the form.

Comment: Turns out you were right! I'm freaking calling it twice! What a shmuck! Thank you all!

Comment: @JoãoDias: If you find yourself in a scenario like this again and you can't pin-point where the second binding is coming from you can use `$(document).off('click', '.save-action').on('click','.save-action',function(){
` to work-around the issue while looking for the cause. `off().on()` should not be a permanent solution because it unbinds all click events from the target but it can be a temporary fix while looking for the real solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give a formal answer (which was discovered in comments):

The script is being called twice.  Either via the HTML attribute, or when being loaded.  You need to make sure you don't run the script twice, or else the event handler will be added twice (and, as such, the function will run twice).

Answer (score -1):

Try binding the action to the class directly

```
$('.save-action').click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
                //var text = tinyMCE.get('#action-desc').getContent(); 
                if($("#form-save-action").validationEngine('validate'))
                {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        data: $("#form-save-action").serialize(),
                        url:"modules/actions/insertaction.php",      

                        success : function (data) {

                           $("#response-message").html(data);

                        }
                    })
                }

            });
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as the form is being loaded by ajax. it needs to be through .on function

Comment: Doesn't jQuery interpret this the exact same way?  I'm pretty sure they trigger the same jQuery function, and it's interpreted the same way

Comment: @cegfault That depends on whether or not he is including the script with each load, or only once at page load.

Comment: @JoãoDias Did you actually try this solution? If you are including this script every time you load the form, this would actually solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, even before the application was running. I just know, by experience, this doesn't work when I'm fully loading every bit of the page through ajax calls